# Does "every N seconds, somebody ____" have proper statistical meaning?

Tags: statistics

For example, the following are identical:

- Every 1 hour, somebody in the world is a victim of identity theft.
- Every year, 0.0001138% of people in the world is a victim of identity theft.

Or

- Every 30 seconds, somebody in the world is a victim of identity theft.
- Every year, 0.01365% of people in the world is a victim of identity theft.

Line 1 of both versions sound scary, while line 2 sounds much less scary. It is a statistic, but does line 1 actually have any real meaning? (or is it in the category of lying by statistics) -- because we are using something that is related to the world population 7.7 billion and let it be divided by something unrelated, which is the amount of hour or seconds in a year.

For example, if the world population is 10 times as today, and the percentage of victims of identity theft remain just the same, now instead of "every 30 seconds", it can be written as "every 3 seconds".  That is, the percentage of identity theft victims actually remain the same, but somehow it can be made 10 times as scary. Compare:

- Buy our security product. Every 3 seconds, somebody in the world is a victim of identity theft.
- Buy our security product. Every year, 0.01365% of people in the world is a victim of identity theft.
- Buy our security product. Every year, there is a 0.0001365 probability you will be a victim of identity theft.

Comment: Would you like it better if they said "on average..."?   Assuming we can attach a meaning to someone being a victim of identity theft at some instance of time, that seems  clear enough.

Comment: it is not an issue of "on average"...

Comment: Well, why not?  "Count the number of victims of identity theft over some long number of hours, $N$,  and divide by $N$.  That works out to close to $1$."

Comment: @lulu please see my last paragraph added in the question

Comment: Still not seeing the problem.  Yes, people have poor intuition as regards very large numbers.   It is easy to sway opinions by the clever presentation of raw data.  All true.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I just add one point:

"Every week, somebody in the world is victim of a crocodile attack"

This has two, even three aspects:

- Luckily I live far away from crocodiles
- I won't visit the zoo anymore
- this means for the concerned regions it really is a big problem

The third - realistic - reaction is to automatically correct for the "improper" statistics.

---

In your "identity theft" example you show the it-could-be-you-anytime, alarmistic touch. Anyone, at any time of day or night.

My "crocodile example *could* mean the opposite: What for us (here in ...) is only an exotic (and macabre) idea, for many people in the world (we all share etc. etc.) it is an almost daily danger.

Answer (score 0):

You are just assuming that the events are uniformly distributed over the time, which is a quite reasonable assumption since a priori you don't have any information on the distribution of the events and you could say that they are usually unrelated between them.